# FileNotFoundError from subprocess.run when executing command from /usr/bin/* - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've seen many similar `subprocess` questions but none of them helped in fixing my problem.

I've written an add-on for Firefox browser using [Web Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) API. This add-on uses [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) API for communicating with native app (which is essentially a Python script).
For reference, my extension and native app (Python script) works similarly to [this](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/native-messaging) example.

In my Python script I'm using `subprocess` module to run a shell command as below:

```py
import subprocess

completedProcess = None
try:
    completedProcess = subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/dig', '+short', '@185.228.168.10', 'stackoverflow.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

This runs fine in Python REPL and I'm able to access output with `completedProcess.stdout`, but fails from within native app (Python script associated with extension) with following traceback (obtained from browser as native app stderr is redirected to browser console):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/sandbox/nativeapp/app/nativeapp.py", line 63, in <module>
    'safe': isSafe(receivedMessage['hostname']),
  File "/home/user/Projects/sandbox/nativeapp/app/nativeapp.py", line 49, in isSafe
    completedProcess = subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/dig', '+short', '@185.228.168.10', hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/dig'
```

I've tried with merging list elements into single string and setting `shell=True`, also `dig` in place of `/usr/bin/dig`, but no success. Interestingly, I can verify that echoing works fine from `subprocess` as in:

`subprocess.run(['echo', 'something'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

But the `subprocess` can't find programs located in `/usr/bin` and `whereis echo` from my terminal reports `/bin/echo`.

Strangely, the traceback mentions `/usr/lib/python3.5` but on my system I don't have directory `python3.5`, although I do have `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7` etc. within `/usr/lib`.

Please help me finding underlying problem and fixing it. Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more debug info, I'm happy to provide.

Comment: What does `whereis dig` tell you? It sounds like `/usr/bin/dig` isn't a valid path.

Comment: @r.ook The output from `whereis dig` is `dig: /usr/bin/dig /usr/share/man/man1/dig.1.gz`, so its available. Also, as I mentioned in question the same code works fine in Python REPL.
I don't know if that can be a case but my blind guess is that as browser launches the Python script, maybe it is being launched in some restricted mode so that it cannot access programs from `/usr/bin/`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After troubleshooting I found that problem was not related to Python or its subprocess module, but actually it was due to Firefox being installed as [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) package in Ubuntu. I don't know much about snap packages but they provide confined environment for installed application.
So, native app (Python script) is launched by extension or Firefox snap in that confined environment and it is unable to find system programs. Also, the Python traceback mention of Python3.5 was due to because script was interpreted by snap packaged version of Python in `/snap/core/current/usr/bin/python3` instead of system global Python. I guess equivalent directory for snap packages are `snap/core/current/bin/` and `/snap/core/current/usr/bin/`. Also, you're not allowed to modify snap directories, so `dig` can't be copied over.

There may exist alternate solution(s) but I decided to remove Firefox snap and reinstall Firefox as regular program from official Mozilla website. Now, everything works fine as expected.